# Fill up svg cumulatively with subsequent calculations

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I am trying to fill my svg (*cumulatively*) with additions of newly calculated quotients.

**Here is a portion of my HTML:**

```
<div style='text-align:center;'>
    <svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 30 42">
        <linearGradient id="lg" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
            <stop stop-color="#61A4FF" offset="0%" id="progress"/>
            <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%" id="F1gst2"/>
            <!-- <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#61A4FF"/>
                <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s" begin="0s"/>
            </stop>
            <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#61A4FF">
                <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  begin="0s"/>
            </stop> -->
        </linearGradient>
        <path id='tear' fill="url(#lg)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.0"
            d=" M  15 3
                Q  16.5 6.8 25 18
                A  12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
                Q  13.5 6.8 15 3z   " />
    </svg>
</div>
```

**And my JavaScript:**

```
function calculate(){
  var numerator = document.getElementById('progressInput').value;
  var denominator = document.getElementById('goalInput').value;
  var quotient = parseFloat(numerator)/parseFloat(denominator);
  progressFill.setAttribute('offset', quotient);
};
```

This code basically refreshes the calculation every time I enter new values into my input fields. It's fine for it to do that the first time I calculate the quotient, but I want it to accumulate the subsequent calculations (and essentially fill up the svg area cumulatively). Is this possible?

E.g., Let's say I first calculate parseFloat(numerator)/parseFloat(denominator) as 2/10 and the svg fills up 20% of the shape on first click. If I want to add another 40% on top of that (so parseFloat(numerator)/parseFloat(denominator) another 4/10), how do I define that as an addition to my code?

I thought I maybe had to write an if-then statement, which I started (but I'm pretty sure it's wrong):

```
function calculate(){
  var numerator = document.getElementById('progressInput').value;
  var denominator = document.getElementById('goalInput').value;
  var quotient = parseFloat(numerator)/parseFloat(denominator);
  if (document.getElementById('progress').offset="0%") {
    progressFill.setAttribute('offset', quotient);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not provided progressInput or goalInput so I've skipped those and used a constant. Each time you click the button the fill changes by 10% though by querying the DOM for the current fill and then adding 10% to it.

```js
function calculate(){
  var quotient = 0.1;
  document.getElementById("progress").offset.baseVal += quotient;
};
```

```html
<div style='text-align:center;'>
<button class="button" class="accumulate" onclick="calculate()">Change</button>

<svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 30 42">
        <linearGradient id="lg" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
            <stop stop-color="#61A4FF" offset="0%" id="progress"/>
            <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%" id="F1gst2"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <path id='tear' fill="url(#lg)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.0"
            d=" M  15 3
                Q  16.5 6.8 25 18
                A  12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
                Q  13.5 6.8 15 3z   " />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect. Thanks a lot! I didn't know about .baseVal until just now. I guess I also didn't even need an if-then statement.